# Is session security enough for java?

Tags: java, jsp, security, session

So I've been looking around for some information on session security and can only find information related to PHP sessions.

Right now my web app authenticates users against the database, and if successful will place their user object (a hibernate entity) into the HttpSession as an attribute.

My web app, then verifies that attribute is set and will use that user object for all future database queries and to confirm the user is authorised.

My web app will be managing money and payments for small businesses and security is a major concern for me. If an attacker was able to impersonate a user they would be able to refund payments and cancel sales. Payments are handled by stripe so card details will be secure, but the user will have API access to initiate refunds.

Will this user object set as a HttpSession attribute be secure enough or should I be adding more stringent security measures? If so can you please suggest additional methods to secure user accounts.

All sessions are conducted over SSL.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe head over to http://security.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically you should never rely only on session when dealing with financial applications in Java/PHP or any other language. Use at least 'one-time' passwords via sms as approval for critical operations like 'refund payments and cancel sales'.

Backing to java sessions, it's a good start to deny storing session id as request parameter - first and easiest protection from session fixation (add this to web.xml):

```
<session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

As complex solution try HDIV 
http://www.hdiv.org/

Comment: Thanks, I've selected this as the answer because of HDIV. Had no idea this security framework existed and feel much better now having it implemented. I have upvoted the rest of the answers because they were all good. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Feel free to contact me if will stick somewhere - I have lot of practice with it)

Answer (score 4):

The session state is kept at server-side, as in PHP. The session ID is sent by the browser as a cookie, as in PHP. It's possible to impersonate a user by stealing his session cookie, but since the traffic is encrypted using HTTPS, the only way to do that would be to steal it from the browser memory, or from the server memory.

Comment: Well, there is CSRF... so you don't necessarily need to have such crazy access to exploit an unguarded session cookie, right?

Comment: Right indeed. By impersonate, I meant using the real application with another user's credentials. CSRF indeed makes it possible to trick a real user to post data to the real app by making him think he's posting them on a different app. The solution to this problem is to use JavaScript to post the forms and to send the session cookie as a HTTP header in addition to sending it as a cookie. The server would then have to check that the header and the cookies match.

Comment: Or session fixation. Or XSS

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I understood the question as "how do Java sessions work". Not as "what are all the security aspects that I need to worry about". XSS doesn't have much to do with session management.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to worry about the https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10 at a minimum.

For your type of app in particular, you should concern yourself first with SQL Injection, Session Fixation, CSRF, XSS and insecure direct object references.

I would start with using a Web Application Firewall like ModSecurity for Apache httpd